# SocketTimeOut Exception after ~20-30 hours of successfully OkHttp GET requests

Tags: java, get, python-requests, okhttp

After 20-30 hours of successfully API requests i get SocketTimeOutException and i can't fix it for about a week.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

***I tried many variations:***

**How I send requests without any custom timeouts:**

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(String.valueOf(message)).build();
response.body().close();
```

**I tried different timeouts: 5 seconds, 120 seconds, 12.000 seconds:**

```
client.setConnectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // connect timeout
client.setReadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    // socket timeout
```

**Also i tried to handle exception. Also i tried to handle exception. I had same exceptions in all 3 tries:**

```
try {
//request (with and without custom timeouts)
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
sendRequest(parametres);
}
```

**Also i tried this:**

```
throws SocketTimeoutException
```

But nothing helped me. I have the same result all the time - all works good for about 20-30 hours and then i have this exception.